# Creating hypercube in R for any dim-d

Tags: r

I am currently working on a R code that works in d dimensions. The only problem is...I am quite new to R and so, I am not sure how to create a d-dimensional hypercube equivalent in R.

Using some notions from other languages, I tried coding

```
## creation of the d-dimensional hypercube
expression <- "u1=(1:20)/20"
   for (i in 2:d) {
     extension <- paste("u", i, "=(1:10)/10",sep = "")          
     expression <- paste(expression, extension, sep = ", ")
}
q <- as.matrix(expand.grid(eval(parse(text=expression)), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=FALSE))
```

but that did not work because the parse function does not appreciate the comma...

Basically, for any dim=d, I need a way to create a matrix or data frame that gives me all the combinations of, for example,

```
 u=(1:10)/10
```

How would you guys proceed?

Sorry for the question that seems quite basic, but I've been googling for quite a while without results.

Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
makeHypercube <- function(dim, ticks) {
    do.call(expand.grid, 
            replicate(dim, seq_len(ticks)/ticks, simplify=FALSE))
}

## Try it out
makeHypercube(dim=3, ticks=2)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1  0.5  0.5  0.5
# 2  1.0  0.5  0.5
# 3  0.5  1.0  0.5
# 4  1.0  1.0  0.5
# 5  0.5  0.5  1.0
# 6  1.0  0.5  1.0
# 7  0.5  1.0  1.0
# 8  1.0  1.0  1.0

## Check that it works in higher dimensions
dim(makeHypercube(dim=10, ticks=3))
## [1] 59049    10
```

Comment: The thing is that the user of the code I am producing will simply pass a dim=d parameter. The solution above would imply that I know the dimension in advance, which is not the case. That is also why I was creating that weird string using the code in my initial question. Any ideas on how to make this more versatile?

Comment: OK, there's a more general solution.

Comment: Is there a good way to avoid looping through the rows of an hypercube created in the above way? I.e. I have a function, say `psi(u)`, and I need to evaluate it at every point of the hybercube. Looping would be very long in high dimensions, so I have tried using various `apply` functions, but that was unsuccessful.